# How do I prevent include breakage

Tags: c++, include, organization

I have a code that contains huge number of cpp / header files. My problem now is, that because many include each other, I occasionally get into a situation that my code doesn't compile, unless I reorder the `#include` directives in random files, which is now necessary basically with creation of any other header file.

This is really very annoying; is there any tip how should I write my c++ code in order to prevent complications with `#include`? I would prefer to split my source code to as many files as possible so that cooperation with other programmers (using git or svn) is easier (more files == lower number of edit conflicts).

One of things that help me now is forward declaration, when I declare the classes from other headers into other files. That helps sometimes, but doesn't resolve all issues; sometimes I just need to change order of `#include`s in random header files or merge multiple files.

Comment: What kind of code are you writing where the *order* of the #includes matters?

Comment: it's QT gui program (source code@ https://github.com/huggle/huggle3-qt-lx )

Comment: If you need to reorder, you may be missing header guards or forward declarations.  Or your headers themselves are not including what they need (though try to reduce this w. forward decls)

Comment: @SB. I do use header guards. I don't use forward declarations for everything, I am even getting compilers errors like core.h:42: error: forward declaration of 'struct EditQuery' when I use forward declaration for some classes in some header files... no idea why

Comment: I did commit the latest code I work on, even if it's broken so that you can check out and try compile yourself, maybe you would find out what is wrong, I just don't see it: https://github.com/huggle/huggle3-qt-lx/commit/2a1df713f3f9af6af50b497693559caf2144a59f

Comment: Include as few header files as possible in other header files, preferably none at all. Just make sure that you declare (not define) classes, structures and variables when needed. Then include as few header files as possible in the sources as well.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that's what I am trying to do, but unfortunately it seems that I am already on minimum. Any removal of any #include from any file result in compiler errors...

Comment: You might also want to refactor the code to minimize the header file dependencies. This can be done by taking all files, and removing *all* header files inclusions, and then add *declarations* when needed, followed by inclusion only when needed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that sounds like a good idea, how do I figure out if include is needed or not, other than trying to remove it and check if it doesn't produce error in compilation?

Comment: Basically that's the best way. :) It can take a lot of time, especially if there are many files, but in the end it will hopefully be more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Not a panacea, but the following guideline helps me a lot.

Assuming your code is composed of files like `MyClassXyz.cpp` with corresponding `MyClassXyz.h`, one class per source file, every cpp-file should include its corresponding header file **first**. That is, `MyClassXyz.cpp` **must** start with the following line:

```
// (possibly after comments)
#include "MyClassXyz.h"
```

This ensures that `MyClassXyz.h` includes all header files (or forward declarations) necessary for its compilation.

I often see code that uses an opposite convention (`#include`ing most general header files first), for example, `MyClassXyz.cpp` starts with

```
#include <vector>
#include <iosfwd>
#include "blah.h"
#include "mytypes.h"
#include "MyClassXyz.h"
```

And `MyClassXyz.h` "goes straight to the point" using stuff defined in the additional headers:

```
#pragma once
// "#include <vector>" missing - a hidden error!
// "#include <iosfwd>" missing - a hidden error!
class MyClassXyz
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(...);
    ...
}
```

While this compiles OK, it gives enormous headaches of the type you describe, when trying to use the class `MyClassXyz` in some other source file.

Comment: Two advantages to including system headers first: (1) it prevents macros in user files from messing up system files (2) it works better with precompiled headers

Comment: This is no excuse for not having headers include the other headers they need, of course.

Comment: Do you think you could explain under what conditions general to specific header ordering gives which enormous headaches?  It isn't clear how this would actually improve the OP's situation.

Comment: @TomKerr Suppose you edit an unrelated file `x.cpp` by adding `#include MyClassXyz.h` to it; then, numerous compilation errors will appear *if* `x.cpp` *doesn't* have `#include <vector>` at the top. If you use my guideline, it would be impossible to have the faulty `MyClassXyz.h` in the `svn` repository, so no possibility of such errors.

Comment: Not including within the header itself is the actual error, stating that directly would make your answer more clear.  Include order may help your compile fail faster, though it has other problems as @BenVoigt has mentioned.  Those problems can be much much worse than casually missing headers.